# Combine two pandas DataFrame into one new

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas DataFrames whose data from different sources, but both DataFrames have the same column names. When combined only one column will keep the name.

Like this:

```
speed_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'ts':  [0,1,3,4],
    'val': [5,4,2,1]
    })

temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'ts':  [0,1,2],
    'val': [9,8,7]
    })
```

And I need to have a result like this:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'ts':    [0,1,2,3,4],
    'speed': [5,4,NaN,1],
    'temp':  [9,8,7,NaN,NaN]
    })
```

Later I will deal with empty cells (here filled with NaN) by copying the values of the previous valid value. And get something like this:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    'ts':    [0,1,2,3,4],
    'speed': [5,4,4,1],
    'temp':  [9,8,7,7,7]
    })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pd.merge`

```
In [406]: (pd.merge(speed_df, temp_df, how='outer', on='ts')
             .rename(columns={'val_x': 'speed','val_y': 'temp'})
             .sort_values(by='ts'))
Out[406]:
   ts  speed  temp
0   0    5.0   9.0
1   1    4.0   8.0
4   2    NaN   7.0
2   3    2.0   NaN
3   4    1.0   NaN

In [407]: (pd.merge(speed_df, temp_df, how='outer', on='ts')
             .rename(columns={'val_x': 'speed', 'val_y': 'temp'})
             .sort_values(by='ts').ffill())
Out[407]:
   ts  speed  temp
0   0    5.0   9.0
1   1    4.0   8.0
4   2    4.0   7.0
2   3    2.0   7.0
3   4    1.0   7.0
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what needed.

Answer (score 0):

Two main DataFrame options, one is `pd.merge` and the other is `pd.fillna`. Here is the code:

```
df = speed_df.merge(temp_df, how='outer', on='ts')
df = df.rename(columns=dict(val_x='speed', val_y='temp'))
df = df.sort_values('ts')
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: This is step by step identical to @JohnGalt's answer

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a left outer join using pandas.merge function

```
d = pd.merge(speed_df,temp_df,on='ts',how='outer').rename(columns=\
{'val_x':'speed','val_y':'temp'})
d = d.sort_values('ts')
d['speed']=d['speed'].fillna(4)
d['temp']=d['temp'].fillna(7)
```

That should return you this:

[image]